# Make method to do difference in specific situation

Tags: c#, oop, domain-driven-design, software-design

In namespace `com.example.website.domain.model`, I have `Project` class, see code:

```
public class Project
{
    private string Name;
    private int Status = 0;
    ... And much more attributes ....

    public Project(string name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public void Publish()
    {
        Status = 1;
    }

    public bool IsPublished()
    {
        return Status == 1;
    }

    public void ChangeName(string newName)
    {
        if (IsPublished()) throw new InvalidOperationException("Not allow to change name after published");
        Name = newName;
    }

    public string GetName()
    {
        return Name;
    }

    ... And much more method ...
}
```

In normal case, user able to change the name of project if the project is not published yet.

I have to create Admin page that able to change name even project was published. I consider to add new method to `Project` that is `public void AdminChangeName(string name)`. But I think `Project` should not expose that kind of method outside admin section (namespace). I want to call same method with same signature without validation.

Comment: I think it's perfectly fine to have a separate `AdminChangeName(...)`  function that does not contain that validation.  It seems like a proper business use-case that your admins may change names of published projects while users may not.  The application layer should make sure that that function is only called by admins (authorization).

Answer (score 0):

The only way to define dynamic polymorphism (it is what you need) is to create some kind of compositions. That is you have to extract check logic in some new class.

Let's take a look at some examples.

### 1.

```
//in domain namespace
public interface INameChangeStrategy {
    public void ChangeName(Project project, string name);
} 

//in general use namespace
public class DefaultNameChangeStrategy : INameChangeStrategy {
    public void ChangeName(Project project, string name) {
        if (project.IsPublished()) throw new InvalidOperationException("Not allow to change name after published");
        project.setName(name);
    }
}

//in admin use namespace
public class AdminNameChangeStrategy : INameChangeStrategy {
    public void ChangeName(Project project, string name) {
        project.setName(name);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the problem is in kind of violation of encapsulation. Project itself 'trusts' to strategies and opens its name property to direct change (method .setName(...)).
Also you have to configure strategy properly depending on context of use - admin or not.

### 2.

Another same solution - add strategy inside Project class:

with interface like

```
public interface INameChangeCheckStrategy {
    public CanChangeName(Project project, string name);
} 

//in general use namespace
public class DefaultNameChangeCheckStrategy : INameChangeCheckStrategy {
    public void ChangeName(Project project, string name) {
        if (project.IsPublished()) throw new InvalidOperationException("Not allow to change name after published");
        //other check logic, i.e. regex match
    }
}

public class Project
{
    private INameChangeCheckStrategy _nameChangeAbilityStrategy;
    ...
    public void ChangeName(string newName)
    {
         _nameChangeAbilityStrategy.CanChangeName(this, newName);
         name = newName;
    }
}
```

in this case encapsulation is holded on a higher level.

Most important thing is that **Strategy implementations must be per-request instances in runtime, so project instance to be properly initialized depending on request**.

Answer (score 0):

Only the admin role can change the name after publishing? If the answer is yes, here is my answer:

You are mixing concerns, permission or role validation belongs to the application concerns not to your domain (in this case the `Project` class).

So you shouldn't have a different method for the same action,  instead before changing the name you shoud validate if the Project is published and the user has the admin role.

I recommend you this video so much, it talks about how to separate concerns [SOLID architecture in slices not layers](https://vimeo.com/131633177)